# update shipping address for shipping method change

Tags: magento-2.1, shipping, shipping-methods, shipping-address

I have create custom shipping method ("Store pickup").

When user fill address details at checkout page at that time shipping method showing.

Now if user select `"Store pickup"`, i want to set store address as shipping address.

How can i set store address as shipping address when user select store pickup shipping method?

Anyone know can give some hint !

Comment: Have you found any solution ?

Comment: yes, i have done some temporary solutions.

Comment: Can you please share ? I have same case, on checkout page user will enter the shipping address so tax is calculating based on that but after that if user select store pickup the we need to calculate tax based on store address.

Comment: @JimitBhavsar Have you found any solution?

Answer (score 0):

add static addess div in this "next: function() {}" function

```
theme > /Magento_Checkout/web/js/model/step-navigator.js
```

show hide static div which is created in step-navigation.js

```
theme > /Magento_Checkout/web/js/view/shipping-information.js

theme > /Magento_Checkout/web/js/model/place-order.js
```

**Tax calculation is done in bellow model files.**

**File 1**

```
<?php
namespace Mymodule\Storepickaddress\Model\Tax\Sales\Total\Quote;

use ClassyLlama\AvaTax\Framework\Interaction\Tax\Get\Proxy as InteractionGet;
use ClassyLlama\AvaTax\Framework\Interaction\TaxCalculation\Proxy as TaxCalculation;
use ClassyLlama\AvaTax\Helper\Config;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address as QuoteAddress;
use Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterfaceFactory as CustomerAddressFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Api\Data\RegionInterfaceFactory as CustomerAddressRegionFactory;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address;
use Magento\Tax\Model\Calculation;
use Magento\Quote\Api\Data\ShippingAssignmentInterface;
use Magento\Framework\DataObject;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\RemoteServiceUnavailableException;
use Magento\GiftWrapping\Model\Total\Quote\Tax\Giftwrapping;
use Magento\Tax\Api\Data\QuoteDetailsInterfaceFactory;
use Magento\Tax\Api\Data\QuoteDetailsItemInterfaceFactory;
use Magento\Tax\Api\Data\TaxClassKeyInterfaceFactory;

class Tax extends \ClassyLlama\AvaTax\Model\Tax\Sales\Total\Quote\Tax
{
     public function collect(
        Quote $quote,
        ShippingAssignmentInterface $shippingAssignment,
        Address\Total $total
    ) {
        // If quote is virtual, getShipping will return billing address, so no need to check if quote is virtual
        $address = $shippingAssignment->getShipping()->getAddress();
        
        if($address->getData('shipping_method')=="mpcustomshipping_express"){
            
            $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
            $storeInformation = $objectManager->create('Magento\Store\Model\Information');
            $store = $objectManager->create('Magento\Store\Model\Store');
            $storeInfo = $storeInformation->getStoreInformationObject($store);
            
            $address['region'] = $storeInfo->getData('region');
            $address['region_id'] = $storeInfo->getData('region_id');
            $address['postcode'] = $storeInfo->getData('postcode'); 
        }

        $storeId = $quote->getStoreId();
        // This will allow a merchant to configure default tax settings for their site using Magento's core tax
        // calculation and AvaTax's calculation will only kick in during cart/checkout. This is useful for countries
        // where merchants are required to display prices including tax (such as some countries that charge VAT tax).
        if (!$this->config->isModuleEnabled($storeId)
            || $this->config->getTaxMode($storeId) == Config::TAX_MODE_NO_ESTIMATE_OR_SUBMIT
            || !$this->config->isAddressTaxable($address, $storeId)
        ) {
            return parent::collect($quote, $shippingAssignment, $total);
        }


        $postcode = $address->getPostcode();
        // If postcode is not present, then collect totals is being run from a context where customer has not submitted
        // their address, such as on the product listing, product detail, or cart page. Once the user enters their
        // postcode in the "Estimate Shipping & Tax" form on the cart page, or submits their shipping address in the
        // checkout, then a postcode will be present; but only send request if the postcode is at least 4 characters.
        if (!$postcode || \strlen($postcode) < 4) {
            return parent::collect($quote, $shippingAssignment, $total);
        }

        $this->clearValues($total);
        if (!$shippingAssignment->getItems()) {
            return $this;
        }

        $taxQuoteDetails = $this->getTaxQuoteDetails($shippingAssignment, $total, $storeId, false);
        $baseTaxQuoteDetails = $this->getTaxQuoteDetails($shippingAssignment, $total, $storeId, true);

        // Get array of tax details
        try {
            $taxDetailsList = $this->interactionGetTax->getTaxDetailsForQuote($quote, $taxQuoteDetails, $baseTaxQuoteDetails, $shippingAssignment);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            switch ($this->config->getErrorAction($quote->getStoreId())) {
                case Config::ERROR_ACTION_DISABLE_CHECKOUT:
                    $this->coreRegistry->register(self::AVATAX_GET_TAX_REQUEST_ERROR, true, true);
                    return parent::collect($quote, $shippingAssignment, $total);
                    break;
                case Config::ERROR_ACTION_ALLOW_CHECKOUT_NATIVE_TAX:
                default:
                    /**
                     * Note: while this should return Magento's tax calculation, the tax calculation may be slightly
                     * off, as these two collect methods will not have run:
                     * @see \Magento\Tax\Model\Sales\Total\Quote\Shipping::collect()
                     * @see \Magento\Tax\Model\Sales\Total\Quote\Subtotal::collect()
                     */
                    return parent::collect($quote, $shippingAssignment, $total);
                    break;
            }
        }

        $taxDetails = $taxDetailsList[InteractionGet::KEY_TAX_DETAILS];
        $baseTaxDetails = $taxDetailsList[InteractionGet::KEY_BASE_TAX_DETAILS];

        $itemsByType = $this->organizeItemTaxDetailsByType($taxDetails, $baseTaxDetails);

        if (isset($itemsByType[self::ITEM_TYPE_PRODUCT])) {
            $this->processProductItems($shippingAssignment, $itemsByType[self::ITEM_TYPE_PRODUCT], $total);
        }

        if (isset($itemsByType[self::ITEM_TYPE_SHIPPING])) {
            $shippingTaxDetails = $itemsByType[self::ITEM_TYPE_SHIPPING][self::ITEM_CODE_SHIPPING][self::KEY_ITEM];
            $baseShippingTaxDetails =
                $itemsByType[self::ITEM_TYPE_SHIPPING][self::ITEM_CODE_SHIPPING][self::KEY_BASE_ITEM];
            $this->processShippingTaxInfo($shippingAssignment, $total, $shippingTaxDetails, $baseShippingTaxDetails);
        }

        //Process taxable items that are not product or shipping
        $this->processExtraTaxables($total, $itemsByType);

        //Save applied taxes for each item and the quote in aggregation
        $this->processAppliedTaxes($total, $shippingAssignment, $itemsByType);

        if ($this->includeExtraTax()) {
            $total->addTotalAmount('extra_tax', $total->getExtraTaxAmount());
            $total->addBaseTotalAmount('extra_tax', $total->getBaseExtraTaxAmount());
        }

        return $this;
    }

   
   
   protected function getTaxQuoteDetails($shippingAssignment, $total, $storeId, $useBaseCurrency)
    {
        // If quote is virtual, getShipping will return billing address, so no need to check if quote is virtual
        $address = $shippingAssignment->getShipping()->getAddress();
        
        if($address->getData('shipping_method')=="mpcustomshipping_express"){
            
            $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
            $storeInformation = $objectManager->create('Magento\Store\Model\Information');
            $store = $objectManager->create('Magento\Store\Model\Store');
            $storeInfo = $storeInformation->getStoreInformationObject($store);
            
            $address['region'] = $storeInfo->getData('region');
            $address['region_id'] = $storeInfo->getData('region_id');
            $address['postcode'] = $storeInfo->getData('postcode'); 
        }
        
        //Setup taxable items
        $priceIncludesTax = $this->_config->priceIncludesTax($address->getQuote()->getStore());
        $itemDataObjects = $this->mapItems($shippingAssignment, $priceIncludesTax, $useBaseCurrency);

        //Add shipping
        $shippingDataObject = $this->getShippingDataObject($shippingAssignment, $total, $useBaseCurrency);
        if ($shippingDataObject != null) {
            $this->addInfoToQuoteDetailsItemForShipping($shippingDataObject, $storeId);
            $itemDataObjects[] = $shippingDataObject;
        }

        //process extra taxable items associated only with quote
        $quoteExtraTaxables = $this->mapQuoteExtraTaxables(
            $this->quoteDetailsItemDataObjectFactory,
            $address,
            $useBaseCurrency
        );
        if (!empty($quoteExtraTaxables)) {
            $itemDataObjects = array_merge($itemDataObjects, $quoteExtraTaxables);
        }

        //Preparation for calling taxCalculationService
        $quoteDetails = $this->prepareQuoteDetails($shippingAssignment, $itemDataObjects);

        return $quoteDetails;
    }

   
}
```

**File 2**

```
<?php
namespace Mymodule\Storepickaddress\Model\Sales\Total\Quote;
/*
use Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterfaceFactory as CustomerAddressFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Api\Data\RegionInterfaceFactory as CustomerAddressRegionFactory;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address;
use Magento\Tax\Api\Data\TaxClassKeyInterface;
use Magento\Tax\Model\Calculation;
use Magento\Quote\Api\Data\ShippingAssignmentInterface;*/

class Tax extends \Magento\Tax\Model\Sales\Total\Quote\Tax

{
    
    public function collect(
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote,
        \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\ShippingAssignmentInterface $shippingAssignment,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total $total
    ) {
        $this->clearValues($total);
        if (!$shippingAssignment->getItems()) {
            return $this;
        }

        $baseTaxDetails = $this->getQuoteTaxDetailsptg($shippingAssignment, $total, true);
        $taxDetails = $this->getQuoteTaxDetailsptg($shippingAssignment, $total, false);

        //Populate address and items with tax calculation results
        $itemsByType = $this->organizeItemTaxDetailsByType($taxDetails, $baseTaxDetails);
        if (isset($itemsByType[self::ITEM_TYPE_PRODUCT])) {
            $this->processProductItems($shippingAssignment, $itemsByType[self::ITEM_TYPE_PRODUCT], $total);
        }

        if (isset($itemsByType[self::ITEM_TYPE_SHIPPING])) {
            $shippingTaxDetails = $itemsByType[self::ITEM_TYPE_SHIPPING][self::ITEM_CODE_SHIPPING][self::KEY_ITEM];
            $baseShippingTaxDetails =
                $itemsByType[self::ITEM_TYPE_SHIPPING][self::ITEM_CODE_SHIPPING][self::KEY_BASE_ITEM];
            $this->processShippingTaxInfo($shippingAssignment, $total, $shippingTaxDetails, $baseShippingTaxDetails);
        }

        //Process taxable items that are not product or shipping
        $this->processExtraTaxables($total, $itemsByType);

        //Save applied taxes for each item and the quote in aggregation
        $this->processAppliedTaxes($total, $shippingAssignment, $itemsByType);

        if ($this->includeExtraTax()) {
            $total->addTotalAmount('extra_tax', $total->getExtraTaxAmount());
            $total->addBaseTotalAmount('extra_tax', $total->getBaseExtraTaxAmount());
        }

        return $this;
    }


    protected function getQuoteTaxDetailsptg($shippingAssignment, $total, $useBaseCurrency)
    {
        $address = $shippingAssignment->getShipping()->getAddress();
        if($address->getData('shipping_method')=="mpcustomshipping_express"){
            
            $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
            $storeInformation = $objectManager->create('Magento\Store\Model\Information');
            $store = $objectManager->create('Magento\Store\Model\Store');
            $storeInfo = $storeInformation->getStoreInformationObject($store);
            
            $address['region'] = $storeInfo->getData('region');
            $address['region_id'] = $storeInfo->getData('region_id');
            $address['postcode'] = $storeInfo->getData('postcode'); 
        }
        
        //Setup taxable items
        $priceIncludesTax = $this->_config->priceIncludesTax($address->getQuote()->getStore());
        $itemDataObjects = $this->mapItems($shippingAssignment, $priceIncludesTax, $useBaseCurrency);

        //Add shipping
        $shippingDataObject = $this->getShippingDataObject($shippingAssignment, $total, $useBaseCurrency);
        if ($shippingDataObject != null) {
            $itemDataObjects[] = $shippingDataObject;
        }

        //process extra taxable items associated only with quote
        $quoteExtraTaxables = $this->mapQuoteExtraTaxables(
            $this->quoteDetailsItemDataObjectFactory,
            $address,
            $useBaseCurrency
        );
        if (!empty($quoteExtraTaxables)) {
            $itemDataObjects = array_merge($itemDataObjects, $quoteExtraTaxables);
        }

        //Preparation for calling taxCalculationService
        $quoteDetails = $this->prepareQuoteDetails($shippingAssignment, $itemDataObjects);

        $taxDetails = $this->taxCalculationService
            ->calculateTax($quoteDetails, $address->getQuote()->getStore()->getStoreId());

        return $taxDetails;
    }
}
```